# Add event listener to dynamic elements at svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm developing dynamic circle chart with svg. For every segment I added different 
`<use id="clone" xlink:href="#circle-small" />` and set `stroke-color`, `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < chartItems.length; i++) {
  currentItem = chartItems[i];
  // create segment element
  useEl = this.createChartPart(currentItem.color);
  chartSvg.appendChild(useEl);

  useEl.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', this.calcStrokeArr(parseFloat(currentItem.percent), 
   roundRadius)  + ' 999');

  // problem
  useEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // do something like add / remove class to current use el
  });

  useEl.setAttribute('id', 'use-' + i);
}
```

For every `use` element add event listener and everything is ok, but where i clicked under area, always selected last `use` element.

this code for `createChartPart` method

```
createChartPart: function(color) {
  var use = document.getElementById('clone');
  var useClone = use.cloneNode(true);

  useClone.setAttribute('xlink:href', "#circle-small");
  useClone.setAttribute('stroke', color);

  return useClone;
}
```

where I wrong? I wanted to selected area from `circle` and change `stroke-width`

Link to demo: https://jsfiddle.net/07d36Lzj/

Thank for all helping! I'sorry if I ask dublicate question, but my research end with unsuccess. Cheers!

**SOLVED!**

I solve problem instead `stroke-dashoffset` i use svg / cirlce attribute `transform` for position for each part of circle. When i used `stroke-dashoffset` click event not work correct at chrome, but with `transform` click event work correctly.

Link to **working demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/0qa94zsm/

Answer (score 0):

did look at your fiddle, replacing `this` by `event.target` in the event listener did improve the behavior, however still not perfect because the "small circle" exist on top of the big one so it can catch the click instead of the "big circle"

[Edit]: click on the border of a big circle element to make it look small again

Anyway here's the fiddle hope that can help !

https://jsfiddle.net/41e2fd9m/

Comment: thanks for helping @MI53RE, but problem come from chrome, when render elements with `stroke-dashoffset` click events work uncorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, did you find a workarround then or is there no option as of now ?